# Using the strcmp() function in C

Tags: c, strcmp, ansi-c

I am writing a program that is supposed to input from the command, and then find the word frequency of the input.  I am having trouble with comparing strings (char arrays) using the strcmp() function.  I have been at it for hours, but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong.  Does it have to do with pointers?  Here my my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char Words[501][21];
    int FreqNumbers[500];
    char temp[21] = "zzzzz";
    char Frequency[5][21];
    int wordCount = 0;
    int numberCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int end = 0;

    do {
        scanf("%20s",Words[wordCount]);
        for(counter = 0;counter < wordCount;counter++){
            if(wordCount > 0){
                if(strcmp(Words[wordCount], Words[counter]) == 0){
                    FreqNumbers[counter]++;
                    break;
                }
                FreqNumbers[wordCount]++;
            }
        }
        wordCount++;
        printf("%s", Words[wordCount - 1]);
        printf("%s", temp);
    } while(strcmp(Words[wordCount],&temp) != 0);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say, because you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: I would say you should debug your code! For instance, what happens with uninitialized values... What's the initial value of each item at `FreqNumbers`?

Comment: The problem that I am having is that the while loop never ends, even when I enter five z's, which then it is supposed to exit the while loop.  And sorry about the poor coding, I am new to C.  =/

Comment: This piece of code is totally ridiculous `wordCount++;
        printf("%s", Words[wordCount - 1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strcmp` function, instead of comparing the word entered by the user with "zzzzz", it was checking the next entry in the array with "zzzzz" And so it was not terminating as there was never a match. (As you do `wordCount++;` before the `strcmp` function)

`char temp[10]` - An array of 10 chars which `temp` will be pointing to. (immutable/constant).

You are passing the `strcmp` function, the address of the variable which points to a memory while it should be given a pointer to the memory.(little confusing but i hope you get the picture). so ideally speaking it should be given.

`strcmp(Words[wordCount],temp);` or `strcmp(Words[wordCount],&temp[0]);`

Although whatever I said might be a little bit confusing. I would highly recommend you to see `KnR` and read on arrays especially `array of chars`

I have made some changes to your code. It is working as required now. Pl have a look and mark as an answer if acceptable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char Words[501][21]={{0}};          //zero initialized
    char *temp = "zzzzz";       //string literal
    int FreqNumbers[500],wordCount = 0,counter = 0;     //other variables

    do {

        scanf("%s",Words[wordCount]);

        for(counter = 0;counter < wordCount;counter++){

            if(wordCount > 0){
                if(strcmp(Words[wordCount], Words[counter]) == 0){
                    FreqNumbers[counter]++;
                    break;
                }
                FreqNumbers[wordCount]++;
            }
        }
        wordCount++;
        printf("%s\n", Words[wordCount - 1]);           //print if required
        printf("%s\n", temp);                           //print if required

    } while(strcmp(Words[wordCount-1],temp) != 0);      

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I also found that using strncmp() was alot easier to use too.  Again thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

```
while(strcmp(Words[wordCount],&temp) != 0);
```

`temp` is already a const `char *`.  Don't use the `&` operator. That will give you a pointer to a const char pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    scanf("%20s",Words[wordCount]);
    wordCount++;

} while(strcmp(Words[wordCount],&temp) != 0);
```

You're just asking for a segfault here. Why on earth are you doing this in a do while loop?

Comment: I don't really see another way of doing it if the user can enter as many words as they want.  I am supposed to keep asking for input until the user enters 'zzzzz'.

Comment: Step through your code. `wordCount` is not going to be what you think it is.